# Google+ REST API. Is there any way of getting from a Post's URL to the activityId?

Tags: rest, google-api, google-plus

In the Google+ REST API, activities.get requires an activityId. Is there any way of getting from a Post's URL to its activityId?

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/get

Because as far as I can see Google's Takeout JSON doesn't include activityId only the URL. Which means there's no easy way for me to use the API to gather other info about the post.

Comment: What post url are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.  But if you mean you want to take the url from google+

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+LindaLawton/posts/8XFzwsumeJj
```

Find the activies id from that so that so that you can get the back from the api about that post.  The anwser is you cant.

8XFzwsumeJj is not an activity id.

The only way i know of to find the activities ids is to get do an activies.list for the user who is currently logged in.

Comment: Yes, that's right, that is what I meant. So it's a little annoying it's impossible.

I guess there are two options.
1) Try and convince google to add activityId to the Takeout stream posts JSON.
2) Try and use .list to grab the same set of posts as in Takeout. The problem being that AFAIK, .list only works for public posts and not communities. Whereas Takeout grabs both.

Comment: Google is in the process of killing Google+ even if they leave The domains version for a while i dont see them doing much development on it.